# no more WakeOnLan on MaaS ver. 2 as Power Type

Tags: maas

Anyone knows why the option WakeOnLan is not more present as Power Type on MaaS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer why it's no longer there, but I can confirm it's not in the API anymore.  That being said, 2.0 is not in final release, and I believe is beta5, working on beta6.  An official answer would be nice if WOL is going to return or if it was removed for a reason.

Previously, 1.9 had `ether_wake` (Wake-on-LAN)

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.9/api.html#ether-wake-wake-on-lan

In 2.0, it is no longer in the API.

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/api.html#power-types

Comment: Someone created a manual plugin at https://github.com/kairen/MAAS-WoL-driver. However, this plugin uses wakeonlan package/binary which for some reason does not seem to work.

So I tried search/replacing every occurence of wakeonlan with etherwake and applying the patch and I still can't get it to work.